# How to frame around an egress window

Tags: basement, windows, framing

we are in the process of framing our new basement after having some foundation work done (steel supports, interior drainage, egress windows). I have a few questions about how to frame around the windows, when considering all the beams on the wall (five over 23 feet, with 2 windows).

1) Is it required that there are studs every 16", or can it be staggered, as long as it's 16" or less? Basically, with the windows and beams, trying to get one exactly every 16" is impossible and it gets crowded with lumber with all the pieces to frame around, coming to a piece every 10" on average on a non-load bearing wall.
2) When framing the windows, do the horizontal pieces need to be supported at every endpoint, or can they just be secured to the nearest vertical stud? Example, with this window:
 [image]
[image]

Should it be framed as the left or right side below?
[image]

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3):

The basic answer is that since this window is already set in the wall the interior framing that you are adding does not provide structural support of the wall over, under and along the sides of the window.

On the other hand you may want to consider how the interior trim and furnishings will be applied. If you intend to apply a wide casing around the window then do consider that having doubled framing around the window can be very nice for nailing into. This can also be very nice above and to the top sides if you intend to install wall mounted drapery rods or bars.

Comment: 100% agree I would use a poly foam seal in between the wood and concrete like a sill seal to prevent rot and create a seal.+

Comment: The point isn't to provide structural support but to place the furring predictably behind the finished surface

Answer (score 0):

Using a 16" OC separation not only addresses structural code (which doesn't apply here) but also serves to keep what's behind the finished wall predictable in the future.

You should frame your studs 16" OC from one of your walls. You should also frame your king+jack studs around windows and doors as future people would expect. If this results in some thick blocks of wood in a few areas then so be it. Lumber isn't that expensive.

If I understand your drawings correctly this is the left one.

You should support the horizontal plate at both sides **and also** continue your 16" OC stud pattern.

I generally have the expectation that there is stud continuation to the floor at the sides of every penetration.

Comment: What all that is needed is furing strips the concrete is the structural support!. Big -

Comment: Of course, he's not supporting the structure with this wall I was saying that the 16" convention isn't just for support. He should still space his furring strips 16" OC

Comment: Change your answer to furing strips then but you specify 2x4. And eliminate king and Jack because these are absolutely not needed! As there is no support required, in fact in many areas I still see sheetrock glued to concrete walls, I don't do this but it is a way some flip guys save a few $.

Comment: The support isn't needed, it's not about support it's about what you'd expect to be behind the wall

Comment: @Matthew Code wise, insulation is required too?

Comment: That I'm not sure about. I would likely put rock wool if it were my project but not sure whether it's required

Comment: "Lumber isn't that expensive." Ahhh... the good ol' days...